# Why do physical quantum maps need to be completely positive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

It has been a real question for me why exactly for studying open quantum systems it is not sufficient for the dynamical maps to be positive and must be completely positive.
what is the physical representation of this concept?
and why is vital?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I assume you are fine with requiring positivity, since if the map is not positive then you will get negative probabilities for some initial states.

If a map $\Phi_s$ in your Hilbert space $\mathcal H_s$ is positive but not completely positive, then you can find a Hilbert space $\mathcal H_a$ such that the map $\Phi_s \otimes 1_a$, belonging to the Hilbert space $\mathcal H_s \otimes \mathcal H_a$, is not positive.

Physically $\Phi_s \otimes 1_a$ represents a map where you don't do anything to this second Hilbert space $\mathcal H_a$, while applying your original map to $\mathcal H_s$, therefore it would be unphysical if this map wasn't positive. What this shows is that positivity is not  a strong enough criteria for you map to be physical, and complete positivity exactly ensures that the map will be positive even with the adition of an arbitrary auxiliary Hilbert space $\mathcal H_a$.